# git merge with --no-commit and selecting old file from current branch

Tags: git

I want to merge `master` into `branch1` and did on `branch1`:

```
git merge master --no-commit
```

After that I got as expected:

```
 You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)

Changes to be committed:
    new file:   own_components/circuit_simulation/component/README.algorithm
    modified:   own_components/circuit_simulation/component/knot.h

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
    both modified:   own_components/circuit_simulation/component/reordered_actions.h
    both modified:   project_m/s60sps/local_reordered_actions.h
```

OK, I now want for 3 of the files the old version of the current branch `branch1`.

I did:

```
[krud@specht first]$ git checkout own_components/circuit_simulation/component/knot.h
Updated 0 paths from the index
```

and also

```
[krud@specht first]$ git checkout --ours own_components/circuit_simulation/component/knot.h
Updated 0 paths from the index
```

Means: Nothing happens.

And in addition, I also want to get back the old version from this branch for one of the files with conflicts:

```
[krud@specht first]$ git checkout --ours project_m/s60sps/local_reordered_actions.h
Updated 0 paths from the index
```

How to pick the current file from the working branch?

Comment: Syntax would be `git checkout @ -- file1 file2 file3`. That is to get the files _as a whole_ from what you had in `branch1`, not just the confliction sections... that basically means to take back changes coming from `master` into those files.

Comment: @eftshift0 Yes, I want to get back the file from the current branch. No changes from master should be merged in. But, as you can see, I simply did not work... any idea?

Comment: What you specified there is _not_ the same syntax I provided.

Comment: A warning: By taking the file from one branch unmodified, you are making a definitive statement (just like with any other merge resolution): "This is the correct way to resolve the conflict". You are *not* only stating a preference that applies only to the feature branch, `branch1`. You cannot delay the correct resolution of the conflict, just in case this was you intent. It means that when you merge `branch1` back to `master` later, you get no new conflict with another opportunity to resolve it differently.

Comment: @j6t's comment is spot on. I didn't raise it because I _assumed_ that the OP _underatands_ what it means to take changes back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gotcha is :

if you don't specify a commit-ish argument, `git checkout <some/file>` will restore on disk the content *from the index*.

Since your `git merge master --no-commit` placed the changes in the index, `git checkout some/file` is a noop.

---

As indicated by @eshift0 in his comment: just add `HEAD` (or its shortcut `@`) to say that you want the content *from the latest commit* and not from the index:

```
git checkout @ -- own_components/circuit_simulation/component/knot.h
```

This will also work for your conflicting file.